# APK doesn't work on phone but App works normal in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I have an App that works without problems in Android Studio, but when I Build the apk and then install it shows stranges behaviors:

1- When App is installing, phone shows me notification that no one permission is necessary for my app (and that is not true, my app works with awareness)

2- After installation, and running, the App crushed, no one screen is showed.

I was thinking that maybe could be a problem with manifest, but as I said in emulator works without problem. First time I see this behavoir. Any idea how to solve it ??

```
03-28 13:15:22.851 7334-7334/com.itelma.tele D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-28 13:15:22.851 7334-7334/com.itelma.tele E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.itelma.tele, PID: 7334
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.itelma.tele.API_AC.FCMInstanceIdService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.itelma.tele.API_AC.FCMInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.itelma.tele-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.itelma.tele-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.itelma.tele-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3841)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1909)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.itelma.tele.API_AC.FCMInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.itelma.tele-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.itelma.tele-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.itelma.tele-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3838)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1909) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itelma.tele.API_AC.FCMInstanceIdService
                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                        ... 10 more
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: post your logcat please.

Comment: is this package name correct com.itelma.tele.API_AC.FCMInstanceIdService ?

Comment: What is `com.itelma.tele.API_AC.FCMInstanceIdService `?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel what do you mean with 'clean your project' ??

Comment: menu->Build->clean Project
i think it is instant run problem

Comment: @JaydeepPatel thanks ! this was the solution I was looking for =)

Comment: always welcome happy to help :-)